# How can I compare, if old date time is less than 20 minutes off current dates?

Tags: java

I have got two dates.

`olddate` and current date as shown below

```
package com;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        // for old date
        String olddate = "2014-10-01 17:26:12";
        DateFormat formatter = null;
        Date convertedDate = null;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(olddate);
        //System.out.println(convertedDate.getMinutes());

        // for new date
        Calendar currentDate1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss");
        String currentdate = formatter1.format(currentDate1.getTime());
        System.out.println("newdate" + currentdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: 20 minutes = 1200000 milliseconds. You can just calculate that currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime()>1200000 . Is this all you want to do?

Comment: You really should at least point out your question, someone with your level of reputation should know this. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats easier than you think.

```
convertedDate.getTime()
```

gives you the date in milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, 0:00 UTC; and

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

gives the current time relative to the same epoch in milliseconds ...